# Javascript check bootstrap checkbox by id

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have the following form :

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='handleChange(this);' id='check11' > Show only price-discounted products
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">
            <div class="checkbox" id='check21'>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='' id='check21'> Show only price-discounted products
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to be able to check the second checkbox automatically with JavaScript once I check the first one. I tried using the following script :

```
<script>        
function handleChange(cb) {
    if(cb.checked == true) {
       alert('Message 1');  
       document.getElementById("check21").checked = true;
    } else {
       alert('Message 2');
       var x = document.getElementById("check21").disabled= false;
    }
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work since I think with bootstrap is a question of classes.

Comment: You have to items with id `check21` (the `div` and the `input`. Your issue might be related to this ?

Comment: nope not from there the issue. correcting the question. thanks!

Comment: So do you have an ID on the div or not? First it was there, then it was gone now it's there again. I created a fiddle without the ID on the div and I believe it works as you requested. http://jsfiddle.net/jxcbyh5x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as Didier pointed out is that you have two elements with the same ID:

```
<div class="checkbox" id='check21'>
```

and

```
<input   type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='' id='check21'>
```

The call to `document.getElementById('check21')` will probably (because the behavior is undefined) return the first one, which in this case is the `<div>` element, not the checkbox.

You must not use the same ID on two HTML elements, so you need to change the ID on one or the other of them.

Comment: Could you check the jsfiddle I linked in my comment to see if that is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uywaxds5/2/

I included boostrap as an external reference.

```
<div class="checkbox" id='check22'>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="discounting" onchange='' id='check21'> Show only price-discounted products
    </label>
</div>
```

Fixing the duplicate id seems to work.
If it does not works, the issue might be in another part of your code.

Comment: Hi there perfect on fiddle but I don't manage to make it work on mine. Should I also add the bonsai library?

Comment: No, bonsai is just a mistake ;) http://jsfiddle.net/uywaxds5/2/ without the library.

Comment: ok so I am definetly lost. I think I have libraries conflicts cauz it still doesn't work. Would there be a way to check any conflict?

Comment: You should add a console.log in your function to exactly know what is :  `document.getElementById("check21")`. You might have another duplicated Id ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different name for the second radio button

```
 <input   type="checkbox" name="discounting21">
```

There can only be one selected radio button belonging to the same group(ie. name).